# VS Code has no intellisenses support to React.js

Tags: reactjs, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code 1.0 on Windows 7 64bit

I have installed some `typings`

*typings.json*

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "react": "registry:dt/react#0.14.0+20160412154040",
    "react-global": "registry:dt/react-global#0.14.0+20160316155526"
  }
}
```

I have also created *jsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "jspm_packages",
        "tmp",
        "temp"
    ]
}
```

I also tried to reference the `typings` files

*app/index.js*

```
/// <reference path="../typings/main.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

I have setup the language to JavaScript React, this supports only HTML completion from within the *.js* files

According to some googling I have tried both `import React from 'react';` and `var React = require('react');`

But I still have no intellisense for React.js from the VS Code, please advise what else should I do

Thanks

Comment: Typings are meant to provide type declarations to be used by typescript. Not javascript. Are you using typescript? They way you described works perfectly fine if you are using typescript.

Comment: @Amid, I'm so sorry that I may not understand things correctly, if I really wanted to use only JavaScript can I get IntelliSense for React.js ? of this is only possible when using TypeScript ?
Thanks

Comment: Actually i was wrong. vscode indeed can use typescript d.ts files for intellisense. the only requirement for it to be working is that 'typings' folder must be sibling or child to jsconfig.json.

Comment: Not sure that this is an issue in your case but by default Typings adds 2 files for node and browser, you should exclude one of them, maybe there is a sort of conflict. Read more [here](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/faq.md#module-resolutions). Ad don't forget to `>Reload JavaScript Project` just in case